# Installing audio libaries for pymedia

Tags: 12.04, sound, python, codecs

I am building pymrdia from a tarball, but when i install i get:

Using UNIX configuration...

OGG          : not found
VORBIS       : not found
FAAD         : not found
MP3LAME      : not found
VORBISENC    : not found
ALSA         : not found

How can I install these?

Answer (score 1):

Go here and write out the commands in a shell script if you know how, or just run the individually: https://kb.hivelocity.net/how-to-install-ffmpeg-ffmpeg-php-flvtool-lame-mplayer-libogg-libvorbis-and-mencoder/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing synaptic package manager

sudo apt-get install synaptic

Then just search for the packages eg. VORBIS

Comment: Im glad this worked for you